# How do you create a new custom preset page size in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, printing

Microsoft excel does not let me create custom page size outside of the preset ones (word lets you make your own size) now this is annoying since we occasionally print in long (8.5in by 13in).

[image]

Notice no option to change the length and width of the paper. The work around we have been doing so far is to print in pdf, adjust printer option(specific to pdf) to have a paper size of 8.5 x 13, save it and print it to the actual printer using pdf.

Does anyone know how to create a new preset bondpaper, i dont have long as an option in my page layout. I also dont mind to just outright edit the legal size to have 13 inches instead of 14in

Comment: I'd expect this to be a PRINTER preset to add... Check Control-panel > Printers > your-personal-printer

Comment: @Hannu i could not find that setting in control pannel , can you be a bit more specific on how to get there? Im using windows 11.

Comment: I do not know exactly, it varies with each printer make and model; but it should be **Inside the printer driver** 's settings - if it exists.

Comment: So what you are saying... the "long" preset sized is based on the printer? oh that is shocking to me, for the many many years i have been using office :D

Comment: At least it is in a reasonably set up OS, I run Ubuntu Linux and have set up my A2-printer (420mm / 17 inches wide) to print elongated (1+ meter, 40+ inches) long pages. This is a very personal custom page size.

Comment: And right now I realize that this was done in GIMP (The free "Photoshop"), nowhere else! (Menu: Print > Paper size > Manage Custom Sizes > ...) I'm really sorry for causing confusion.